# Is there a good way to share configuration between apps in Azure?

Tags: azure, configuration, azure-web-app-service, azure-functions

We have a large system built in Azure apps. It is made up of an App Service for our API and several Functions Apps for backend processing.

What's the best way to allow these apps to share configuration?

We use ARM templates currently to set up the environment variables for each app, which is fine for deploy-time, but there's nothing to keep the config in sync between the apps.

A use case might be a feature flag that controls whether a sub-system is operational. We might want this flag to be used in the API and a Functions App. At present we can manually go in and set the variable in each of the apps, but it would be easier to manage if we only had to do it in one location.

Ideally, any update to the config would be detected by Azure and trigger a restart of the service, as currently happens with the native implementation.

Is there a good, off-the-shelf, way to do this? Or will I be rolling my own with a table in a database and a lightweight function?

Comment: have you considered azure key vault ?

Comment: @ImranArshad That's not a bad plan. We're already using it for secrets.

Comment: There is also the new App Configuration service :) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/overview

Comment: @juunas If you expanded that to an answer, it might be a contender

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way would be to use the new App Configuration service: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/overview.

It is meant for sharing configuration settings across components.

Note it is not meant for secrets, that's what Key Vault is for.

Answer (score 2):

There is a guidance/design pattern for this from Microsoft, it can be found from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/external-configuration-store).

Answer (score 1):

Best Practice in Architecture: You can use the external configuration store pattern and use a Redis Cache to share the configuration between multiple applications as described in here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/external-configuration-store

The approach is you can get this data from Appsettings for each environement (this can be automated in CI/CD pipeline). On first connection you store the data in RedisCache.

For senstive data: Use Keyvault to store the secrets/keys/certificates.